# How to Use OpenCV Submodule In Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, opencv3.3

How to use createLBPHFaceRecognizer() in opencv3.3, and Python 2.7.13?

I Used Windows 64 bit OS

because i find an error in syntax :

```
import os
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

recognizer = cv2.createLBPHFaceRecognizer()
path='dataSet'
```

> Error : recognizer = cv2.createLBPHFaceRecognizer()
>
> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute
>   'createLBPHFaceRecognizer'

Comment: Please refer to this [link](http://answers.opencv.org/question/137349/how-can-i-use-createlbphfacerecognizer-in-opencv32-python3/)

Answer (score 0):

You need compile OpenCV from source. Download both [opencv](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/releases) and [opencv_contrib](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/releases).

In `opencv_contrib` source, there is a folder called `modules`, delete you don't use.

I don't how to compile it on Windows. There[(OpenCV 3 Tutorials, Resources, and Guides)](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/opencv-tutorials-resources-guides/) are some tutorials for install OpenCV(Linux, macOS, etc), but no Windows version. You can refer to relevant information for compile OpenCV from source on Windows.